# Redirecting stdout of a python code to a file WITHOUT letting python to keep it locked

Tags: python, linux, file-io, stdout

I am trying the most simple method of redirecting the `stdout` of a **python** code to a file using a command such as below.

```
python foo.py > SmokeyStover.log
```

This works fine except I need to stop my **python** code to be able to read the added logs into this log file and the result for commands such as

```
tail -f SmokeyStover.log
```

while the code is running, using the python interpreter, is no incoming logs in the real time stream of logs getting appended to this file continuously.

I also used other approaches to redirect the `stdio` inside the **python** code using commands such as following and the file simply doesn't get flushed.

```
sys.stdout = open('SmokeyStover.log', 'a')
```

Comment: Output of `python foo.py` will be redirected to `SmokeyStover.log`. But until you stop `python foo.py` it will not flush the data to `SmokeyStover.log` this is what my understanding is.

Comment: Try `python -u foo.py > SmokeyStover.log` for unbuffered output. If this is linux you could d osomething like `python foo.py | tee xxx.log`

Answer (score 2):

Probably you will have to flush the buffer manually, for instance:

```
import sys
import time


for i in range(100):
    print "number is %s " %i
    time.sleep(1)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: from what I was reading it's also better that `flush()` is followed by `os.fsync(sys.stdout)`.